# How to create a 2 minute countdown timer using angular 7?

Tags: angular6

I wont to create 2 minute countdown timer. I also try this code but it's for sec anyone please tell me how can i create 2 minute countdown Timer using `angular 7 (typescript)`

```
timer() {

   this.countdown().subscribe(
     t => {
       this.value1 = t
     },
     null,
     () => {

     }
   );
   this.start(60);
 }
```

// 60 sec count code

```
 countdown(): Observable<number> {
   return this._countdown.asObservable();
 }

 private isCounting = false;
 start(count: number): void {
   if (!this.isCounting) {
     this.isCounting = true;
     timer(0, 1000).pipe(
       takeWhile(t => t < count),
       map(t => count - t)
     ).subscribe(
       t => this._countdown.next(t),
       null,
       () => {
         this._countdown.complete();
         this.isCounting = false;
         this._countdown = new Subject<number>();
       }
     );
   }
 }
```